# Wildfly see resources from external jar in different ears

Tags: wildfly

Is it possibile to scan some directories to find all jars and add them as dependencies in ears at runtime?

I'm using wildfly 8.1.0 final.

For example we have two separated ear:

- ear1
- ear2

And an external jar with some jsf managed beans, facelets, and static content (images, css, js):

- jar1

Does exist any way to make all resources in jar1 to be accessible from ear1 and ear2 without put jar1 as module in ear1 or ear2?

I don't know any other way than add jar1 as dependency in ear1 and ear2 and redeploy ear1 and ear2.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Java EE way is create EJB services in war1 module. After this you should use JNDI name lookup in ear1, ear2 and consume EJB interfaces provided by war1. If you need dynamicly add JSF resources (jsf pages, and static files) you should write custom implementation of javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper. Your implementation should transfer resource request to war1 module (using EJB interface).

In this case you have weak dependency between ear1,ear2 and war1 modules. Also you can have a set of war modules and some registry with JNDI names or use list method: [Wildfly jndi list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463970/how-to-list-all-jndi-entries-in-javaglobal-namespace).

But I am not sure how transfer call to war1 managed bean. I think you should use EJB in war1 module, and write some proxy JSF bean in ear1,ear2.

Comment: Maybe you have seen question before update. I need something like programmatically add dependency at runtime scanning jars from some folders.

Comment: if you need to do this programmatically best and pretty much only way is to implement your own subsystem that has deployment unit processor that does that.